# python - Joining two columns pandas - returning NA if any value is NA, however need to return real join

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student_id': [71, 63, 23],
                   'student_name': [nan, 'Peter Andrews', 'Amy Powers'],
                   })
```

I am creating new column column which joins id + name using

`df['student_id_name'] = df['student_id'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['student_name']`

Needed output:

`{student_id_name : [71, 63 Peter Andrews, 23 Amy Powers]}`

What I get:

`{student_id_name : [nan, 63 Peter Andrews, 23 Amy Powers]}`

May you help to get to expected outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) with `na_rep` parameter, last remove possible trailing spaces by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['student_id_name'] = (df['student_id'].astype(str).str.cat(df['student_name'], 
                                                    sep=' ', na_rep='').str.strip())
print (df)
   student_id   student_name   student_id_name
0          71            NaN                71
1          63  Peter Andrews  63 Peter Andrews
2          23     Amy Powers     23 Amy Powers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna()` to cleanup missing/blank values in dataframe. Then your original expression will work. Note that this will actually replace nan with replace value used:

```py
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({'student_id': [71, 63, 23],
                   'student_name': [math.nan, 'Peter Andrews', 'Amy Powers'],
                   })
# 
df = df.fillna('')
df['student_id_name'] = df['student_id'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['student_name']

[Out]:
   student_id   student_name   student_id_name
0          71                              71 
1          63  Peter Andrews  63 Peter Andrews
2          23     Amy Powers     23 Amy Powers
```